# Laravel 5.5 Restful Api post values with parameters

Tags: api, laravel-5.5

I have created an api that posts values but in my Routes api, I would like to pass parameters in my url.My route is as follows

```
Route::resource('api/testV1/add?api_token={token}','Api\AddmeController',['only'=>['store','index']]);
```

For test purposes I just want it to return the values I posted eg api_token.I Currently get Page Not Found when I run the url in postman (POST method)
(localhost:8000/api/testV1/add?api_token=12345)
In my controller

```
public function store(Request $request,$token)
{
     $filters = Input::only('api_token');
     $add = applyFilters($filters)->all();

    return $add;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the request to get the parameters like this:

`$request->route("api_token")`

If you aren't passing a `$request` value to the arguments of the function then you could access it the same using this:

`request()->route("api_token")`

### Edit

You need to use `Input::get()`

Try this: `Input::get('api_token')`. I have just tested this in my project and it worked fine on a POST request.

It appears my original answer only works inside FormRequests, my apologies.

If you are getting `Page not found` when accessing your route, it's possible you haven't cached the changes to the Route files. Try running this command in the terminal: `php artisan route:cache`.

You can also see a list of all active Routes using this command: `php artisan route:list`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: My apologies. The code I sent you was from a FormRequest I was using. I tested this in a normal controller function and you are right, it did not work. Using `Input::get()` works though! Try that. Are you still getting `Page not found`? If so, run `php artisan route:cache` from the terminal. You can confirm which routes are active by using `php artisan route:list`. Let me know if you still have issues.